# Why am I unable to view pictures sent to me by MMS from an iPhone?

Tags: htc-desire, images

If I receive a picture message from a friend with an iPhone, the MMS message appears with a "Slideshow" attachment.  When I try to open the Slideshow, I get a message saying, "Unsupported media type".

Can anyone help?  Why can't I view these messages?

Edit: I'm running the [T-mod ROM](http://www.t-mod.org/) with Froyo (2.2b)

Comment: I get exactly the same thing happen to me from my gf's phone. Iphone 4....but when i get my parents to send me pics from their ipone4's it works ok so im thinking it's her phone...don't spose anyone would have any idea what i could do to her phone to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: @Trent: You probably want to ask that on the [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

A few things you could try... (good luck!)

---

**Reset the Messaging App**

Settings>Menu>Applications>Manage applications>Soft menu key>Filter>All.  Scroll to the Messaging App and tap that. Tap Clear Data, Clear Defaults, then Force Stop. Powercycle the phone. Test MMS. If it fails to resolve the issue go the messaging application and tap the Menu soft key>Settings>Menu soft key again> Restore Default Settings.

---

**Alternative Messaging Apps**

Try ChompSMS or Handcent from the Market.

---

**Download the message first**

I forget how you do this exactly :o/ Maybe long press or menu button? Then try viewing the image from the Gallery app.

Answer (score 0):

When my friend's send me photos through a text message through their iPhone's i am unable to retrive the message. It says that it is downloadimg... but it never downloads. Why is this the case?

Comment: Sounds like a different error, but incidentally I haven't figured mine out either...